# Display image gallery on clicking separate image using Matrix

Tags: matrix, assets, pixelandtonic, image-galleries

I've recently come across a bit of an issue that's got me stumped, here goes.

I have a Matrix field called {images} with the following fields within it;

- `project_image` (Assets fieldtype)
- `project_title`
- `project_additional_images` (Assets fieldtype)

On the front end of the site the `project_image` displays. However on clicking the `project_image` I would like to trigger a lightbox plugin (Swipebox) which in turn displays the multiple images added in `project_additional_images`.

My code is as follows

```
{images}

<li>
    <a class="swipebox" href="{project_additional_images:url}" rel="gallery-{row_id}">

                {exp:ce_img:single src="{project_image}"  
                    crop="yes" 
                    allow_scale_larger="no" 
                    class="project-img" alt="{title}"  
                    width="230" 
                    height="230" 
                    quality="100" 
                    filter="auto_sharpen"}

     </a>     

</li><!-- end item -->

{/images}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this. Looking at the code above, that currently only gets me halfway, in that it will only show a single image from the `project_additional_gallery` field. I would ideally need it to show multiple images. The `gallery-{row_id}` was a shot in the dark. If anyone offer some advice on this that would be much appreciated.

As you can see above, the chunk of markup also makes use of CE Image and [Swipebox](http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/)

Thanks
Adam

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not displaying link to the other images anywhere in your template, you'll need to take a different approach. It looks like you can have Swipebox [load images dynamically](http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/#dynamic) by passing it an array.

So start by adding your gallery images as a comma-separated list inside of a `data` attribute on your link:

```
{images}
<li>
    <a class="gallery" href="{project_additional_images:url}" data-images="{project_additional_images backspace="1"}{url},{/project_additional_images}">
        {exp:ce_img:single src="{project_image}"  crop="yes" allow_scale_larger="no" class="project-img" alt="{title}"  width="230" height="230" quality="100" filter="auto_sharpen"}
     </a>     
</li><!-- end item -->
{/images}
```

Then your JavaScript gets a little bit more complex:

```
$('.gallery').each(function()
{
    images_string = $(this).data('images').split(',');
    images_array = [];
    $(images_string).each(function(index, el)
    {
        images_array.push({href: el});
    });
    $(this).click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.swipebox(images_array);
    });
});
```

Noticed I changed the class from `swipebox` to `gallery` so that the default Swipebox behaviour doesn't attach to the element.

This is untested, but it should get you close.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, definitely progress. I am noticing that when I hover over `project_image` the URL its linking to is correct and is pointing to the right image, however on clicking the link and triggering the popup, it displays the image(s) of the last `project_image` instance.

Comment: If you look at the source code, does the `data-images` attribute contain the correct image names?

Comment: Yes, all correct, with multiple images separated by comma and making use of backspace. The URL's are spot on but somehow when you trigger `$.swipebox(images_array);` it seems to revert to the last group of `project_additional_images` in the matrix

Comment: Hmm. Try using `$(this).on('click', function(e)` instead of `$(this).click(function(e)`.

Comment: Still no joy unfortunately, I'm not an expert by any stretch, but could the problem be stemming from the triggering of swipebox. It seems everything prior to that event is how it should be